# custom tooltips with react-chartjs-2 library

Tags: chart.js

I am having issue with the default tooltip that chartjs provides as I can not add html inside the tooltips. I had been looking at how i can add the html/jsx inside the tooltip. I see an example with using customized tooltips here [Chart JS Show HTML in Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025737/chart-js-show-html-in-tooltip).
can someone point me an example how to achieve the same with react-chartjs-2 library?

Comment: I was also trying to customize the tooltip for react-chartjs-2  and the answer present here helped me implement it quickly
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44010778/4554386

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the `custom` callback in the tooltip property to define your own positioning and set the hovered dataset in the component state

```
state = {
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  date: '',
  value: 0,
};

_chartRef = React.createRef();

setPositionAndData = (top, left, date, value) => {
  this.setState({top, left, date, value});
};

render() {
  chartOptions = {
    "tooltips": {
      "enabled": false,
      "mode": "x",
      "intersect": false,
      "custom": (tooltipModel) => {
        // if chart is not defined, return early
        chart = this._chartRef.current;
        if (!chart) {
          return;
        }

        // hide the tooltip when chartjs determines you've hovered out
        if (tooltipModel.opacity === 0) {
          this.hide();
          return;
        }

        const position = chart.chartInstance.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

        // assuming your tooltip is `position: fixed`
        // set position of tooltip
        const left = position.left + tooltipModel.caretX;
        const top = position.top + tooltipModel.caretY;

        // set values for display of data in the tooltip
        const date = tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].xLabel;
        const value = tooltipModel.dataPoints[0].yLabel;

        this.setPositionAndData({top, left, date, value});
      },
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Line data={data} options={chartOptions} ref={this._chartRef} />
      { this.state.showTooltip
        ? <Tooltip style={{top: this.state.top, left: this.state.left}}>
            <div>Date: {this.state.date}</div>
            <div>Value: {this.state.value}</div>
          </Tooltip>
        : null
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

You can use the tooltips supplied by [React Popper Tooltip](https://github.com/mohsinulhaq/react-popper-tooltip) or roll your own - pass the `top` and `left` to the tooltip for positioning, and the `date` and `value` (in my example) should be used to show the data in the tooltip.

Comment: Great answer, but please update it to include `pageXOffset` for left and `pageYOffset` for top, otherwise it doesn't take into account scrolling. The docs on react-chartjs don't take this into account either.

`const left = position.left + pageXOffset + tooltipModel.caretX;`
`const top = position.top + pageYOffset + tooltipModel.caretY;`

Comment: Thanks @MartinDawson. Your comment has value though it depends on the situation. If your tooltip is `position:absolute`, then pageOffsets are needed, but if it's `position:fixed`, then it's not.

Comment: This answer breaks when the chart is redrawn because canvas is null. I raised an issue for it: https://github.com/jerairrest/react-chartjs-2/issues/225

Comment: I'm not really sure about the reason, but the same thing started happening to me lately while creating charts which rerender. (Maybe I had just never encountered this earlier). I solved it by setting the ref as such: `<Line ref={this._setRef} ... />`, and `_setRef = (c) => { this._chart = c; }`. Then just doing `this._chart.chart_instance.canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` in the tooltip callback.

Comment: can you help me with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58709699/change-tool-tip-direction-in-react-chartjs2?noredirect=1#comment103716906_58709699

Answer (score 5):

If anyone looking answer customization of tooltip and gradient chart here is my code:

**My Packages:**

```
"react": "^17.0.2"
"chart.js": "^3.7.1"
"react-chartjs-2": "^4.1.0"
"tailwindcss": "^3.0.23"
```

**ToopTip Component:**

```
import React, { memo } from "react";
import { monetarySuffix } from "@src/helpers/util";
// tooltip.js
const GraphTooltip = ({ data, position, visibility }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className={`absolute px-4 py-3.5 rounded-lg shadow-lg bg-chart-label-gradient text-white overflow-hidden transition-all duration-300 hover:!visible
      ${visibility ? "visible" : "invisible"}
        `}
      style={{
        top: position?.top,
        left: position?.left,
      }}
    >
      {data && (
        <>
          <h5 className="w-full mb-1.5 block text-[12px] uppercase">
            {data.title}
          </h5>

          <ul className="divide-y divide-gray-100/60">
            {data.dataPoints.map((val, index) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={index}
                  className="m-0 py-1.5 text-base font-rubik font-medium text-left capitalize last:pb-0"
                >
                  {val?.dataset.label}
                  {":"} {monetarySuffix(val?.raw)}
                </li>
              );
            })}
          </ul>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(GraphTooltip);
```

**Chart Component**

```
import React, { useMemo, useState, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler,
} from 'chart.js';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import GraphTooltip from './chart-tooltip';

ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  Filler
);

const GradientChart = () => {
  const [tooltipVisible, setTooltipVisible] = useState(false);
  const [tooltipData, setTooltipData] = useState(null);
  const [tooltipPos, setTooltipPos] = useState(null);

  const chartRef = useRef(null);

  const data = {
    labels: [
      'January',
      'February',
      'March',
      'April',
      'May',
      'June',
      'July',
      'Agust',
      'September',
      'October',
      'November',
      'December',
    ],
    datasets: [
      {
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: (context) => {
          const chart = context.chart;
          const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;

          if (!chartArea) {
            return;
          }
          return createGradient(
            ctx,
            chartArea,
            '#F46079',
            '#F46079',
            'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
          );
        },
        borderColor: '#F46079',
        lineTension: 0.4,
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#FE5670',
        pointBorderColor: '#ffffff',
        pointBorderWidth: 1.5,
        label: 'Sales',
        data: [
          4500, 2800, 4400, 2800, 3000, 2500, 3500, 2800, 3000, 4000, 2600,
          3000,
        ],
      },
      {
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: (context) => {
          const chart = context.chart;
          const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;

          if (!chartArea) {
            return;
          }
          return createGradient(
            ctx,
            chartArea,
            '#2f4b7c',
            '#2f4b7c',
            'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
          );
        },
        borderColor: '#2f4b7c',
        lineTension: 0.4,
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#FE5670',
        pointBorderColor: '#ffffff',
        pointBorderWidth: 1.5,
        label: 'Commision',
        data: [
          5000, 3500, 3000, 5500, 5000, 3500, 6000, 1500, 2000, 1800, 1500,
          2800,
        ],
      },
      {
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: (context) => {
          const chart = context.chart;
          const { ctx, chartArea } = chart;

          if (!chartArea) {
            return;
          }
          return createGradient(
            ctx,
            chartArea,
            '#665191',
            '#665191',
            'rgba(255,255,255,0)'
          );
        },
        borderColor: '#665191',
        lineTension: 0.4,
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 10,
        pointBackgroundColor: '#FE5670',
        pointBorderColor: '#ffffff',
        pointBorderWidth: 1.5,
        label: 'Transaction',
        data: [
          1000, 2000, 1500, 2000, 1800, 1500, 2800, 2800, 3000, 2500, 3500,
          2800,
        ],
      },
    ],
  };

  const createGradient = (ctx, chartArea, c1, c2, c3) => {
    const chartWidth = chartArea.right - chartArea.left;
    const chartHeight = chartArea.bottom - chartArea.top;
    const gradient = '';
    const width = '';
    const height = '';
    if (!gradient || width !== chartWidth || height !== chartHeight) {
      width = chartWidth;
      height = chartHeight;
      gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(
        0,
        chartArea.bottom,
        0,
        chartArea.top
      );
      gradient.addColorStop(0, c3);
      gradient.addColorStop(0.5, c2);
      gradient.addColorStop(1, c1);
    }
    return gradient;
  };

  const customTooltip = useCallback((context) => {
    if (context.tooltip.opacity == 0) {
      // hide tooltip visibilty
      setTooltipVisible(false);
      return;
    }

    const chart = chartRef.current;
    const canvas = chart.canvas;
    if (canvas) {
      // enable tooltip visibilty
      setTooltipVisible(true);

      // set position of tooltip
      const left = context.tooltip.x;
      const top = context.tooltip.y;

      // handle tooltip multiple rerender
      if (tooltipPos?.top != top) {
        setTooltipPos({ top: top, left: left });
        setTooltipData(context.tooltip);
      }
    }
  });

  const options = useMemo(() => ({
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      y: {
        grid: {
          display: false,
        },
      },
    },
    interaction: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false,
    },
    plugins: {
      legend: {
        display: false,
      },
      title: {
        display: false,
      },
      tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
        position: 'nearest',
        external: customTooltip,
      },
    },
  }));

  return (
    <div className="grad-chart-wrapper w-full relative">
      <Line options={{ ...options }} data={data} ref={chartRef} />

      {tooltipPos && (
        <GraphTooltip
          data={tooltipData}
          position={tooltipPos}
          visibility={tooltipVisible}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default GradientChart;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, although I have to tweak the snippet to suit my needs because I was using the `Bar` chart, the tooltip works flawlessly.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Really happy the code was helpful. @Cuado

Comment: Thank you for this! Working as expected, best example I could find online

Answer (score 0):

Remember to think in React here (which is not always easy).  Use the `mycustomtooltipfunction` to set state in your React class (specifically, add the tooltip that is passed to `mycustometooltipfunction` to the state - this will result in `render` being invoked.  Now in the `render` function of your class, check if that state exists and add the JSX for your tooltip.

```
class MyChart extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            tooltip : undefined
        };
    }

    showTooltip = (tooltip) => {
        if (tooltip.opacity === 0) {
            this.setState({
                tooltip : undefined
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({ 
                tooltip
            });
        }
     }

     render() {
         const { tooltip } = this.state;

         let options = {
             ...
             tooltips : {
                 enabled : false,
                 custom : this.showTooltip,
             }
         }

         let myTooltip;
         if (tooltip) {
           // MAKE YOUR TOOLTIP HERE - using the tooltip from this.state.tooltip, or even have a tooltip JSX class
         }

         return (
             <div>
                 {myTooltip}
                 <Line ref="mygraph" key={graphKey} data={data} options={options} height={graphHeight} width={graphWidth}/>
             </div>
         )
    }
}
```

`

Comment: appreciate your reply, your answer is really vague. Do you have a working example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.chart.chart_instance.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```

If you get some error with `chart_instance` you should check parent of element value.

Try this:

```
this.chart.chartInstance.canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
```