# How to add html tags inside chartjs callback footer function

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, chart.js

I am trying to add an anchor tag inside a callback footer of chartjs. 
As per this solution, [Chart JS Show HTML in Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39025737/chart-js-show-html-in-tooltip) callbacks doesn't allow us to use HTML tags inside. 
I tried to create a custom tooltip but it is also not working in my case as I want to add an anchor upon clicking a tooltip inside a callback.

What options do I have now?

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      footer: (tooltipItems, data) => {
        const tooltipData = [];
        let jobLink = '';
        if (tooltipItems[0].index > 0) {
          tooltipDataSet = data.datasets[tooltipItems[0].datasetIndex].data;

          // make job link against job id
            jobLink = `<a href="https://xyz.comjobs/selectedJob=${tooltipDataSet.job_id}"> Link </a>`;

        }
        jobLink = `Job(${jobLink})`;
        tooltipData.push(somedata, `Δ ${otherdata} (${percentagedata}%)`, jobLink);
        return tooltipData;
      },
    },
  },
```

I am expecting it to be a link but it is rendered as text. 
How can I use this inside a callback?